# Network programming 0 bytes of data

Tags: netty

Could you please, tell me weather or not the following [ACK] is meant as client telling the server that it received message or it meant as client app is actually sending 0 bytes of data to server?

My assumption is: 
[ACK] is meant as the "confirmation" 
IF the client app actually sends the 0 bytes of data WireShark would indicate it as [PSH ACK] instead of [ACK].
Is my understanding correct?

i.e)

5555 > 6666 [ACK] Seq=15 Ack=15 Win=32768 Len=0  | Client --> Server

Actually, there is a possibility that client app actually send 0 bytes of data in general in terms of the socket/networking programming?
Is there any specific meaning when client app send 0 bytes of data?

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Read up on TCP. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol

Comment: @MattBall It seems to me that [ACK] is always displayed during the TCP connection. So, what I want to make sure is: [ACK] itself is solely used for a indication of confirmation or it is no longer a solely an [ACK] but [PSH ACK] or something if the client is actually sending the application data. Could you, please help me understand this concept?

Comment: @MattBall I read the wiki and understood that the message is not delivered to application unless the message has [PSH]. So, now I am confident that [ACK] alone is only meant as confirmation, and the above traffic ([ACK] Seq=15 Ack=15 Win=32768 Len=0) does not mean it is sending 0 bytes of data to application.Thanks!